# Median, mode, mean in Python

Tags: python, regex, statistics

I'm trying to to load matched regex in to the list and then calculate median, mode and mean.

The data file (pc1.txt):

```
2017-04-16 13:32:59 
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\processor(_total)\% processor time : 1.05614841124945
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\memory\% committed bytes in use : 5.50960924380334

2017-04-16 13:33:05
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\processor(_total)\% processor time : 1.08875159384721
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\memory\% committed bytes in use : 5.5102938969471

2017-04-16 13:33:10
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\processor(_total)\% processor time : 0
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\memory\% committed bytes in use : 5.46869437193207

BootTime 200938

 ------------------------------------ 
 ------------------------------------ 

2017-04-16 13:40:11 
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\processor(_total)\% processor time : 4.37510327488846
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\memory\% committed bytes in use : 4.438387242009

2017-04-16 13:40:17
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\processor(_total)\% processor time : 1.90625777477218
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\memory\% committed bytes in use : 4.44426156598249

2017-04-16 13:40:22
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\processor(_total)\% processor time : 0.078229917076289
\\desktop-XXXXXXX\memory\% committed bytes in use : 4.44589104046464

BootTime 69920
```

Regex to find values:

```
Processor: ^[\\].+processor.+[: ](\d*\.?\d*)
Memory: ^[\\].+memory.+[: ](\d*\.?\d*)
Boottime: ^BootTime.(\d+)
```

So far I tried to:

```
with open('pc1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        re.findall(processor, f)
```

However, I'm unable to 1) match values; 2) put the in the list; 3) calculate median, mode and mean.

I have basic knowlege how to calculate mode:

```
from statistics import mode
mode([value1, value2])
```

But still I can't put all pieces together. Also, I'm open for any other programming language which can handle statistics in easy/easier way.

Comment: What exactly is `processor_regex`?

Comment: which python version are you using ?

Comment: Python2.7. Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You need to give us the version of python you're using, tell us what the actual error is (if you're getting one) or what you're getting and how it differs from what you expect. Also, limit questions to a single topic. You're asking two very unrelated things here and it's likely you're only going to get an answer on the regular expression. Your code has an error: you need to pass `line` to `findall`, not `f`. `findall` takes a string, not a file descriptor. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: what do you mean by ***Not python3*** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matches from the text file are `strings` not `floats`, we need to convert them in order to get the `median` and `mean`, I used `numpy` instead on `statistics`, i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
import re

with open('pc1.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
    processor = re.findall(r"processor time : ([\d.]+)", data, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    processor = [float(i) for i in processor] # we convert the matching list of strings to floats
    if processor:
        print (np.median(processor))
        print (np.mean(processor))

    memory = re.findall(r"memory\\%.*?: ([\d.]+)", data, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    memory = [float(i) for i in memory] # we convert the matching list of strings to floats
    if memory:
        print (np.median(memory))
        print (np.mean(memory))

    boot_time = re.findall(r"BootTime ([\d]+)", data, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    boot_time = [float(i) for i in boot_time]  # we convert the matching list of strings to floats
    if boot_time:
        print (np.median(boot_time))
        print (np.mean(boot_time))
```

Comment: For some reason, the code doesn't output anything. Even tho it looks correct.

Comment: There is no output.

Comment: I honestly don't know what can be wrong when you execute the code, on my side it works as expected.

Comment: Oh, snap! Found the problem, white spaces cause regex mismatches.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found the problem. GL

Comment: You may want to use `median` instead of `mean` to avoid outliers (extreme values that influence the `mean` result)